# Get Incremented IDs when Identity is not set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where primary key column has IDENTITY OFF. While performing an INSERT, I pick the max(Cust_Id)+1 and inserts.

But sometimes there are multiple records to be inserted using a query similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO <table_1>
SELECT 
   (SELECT MAX(Cust_Id)+1 FROM <table_1>),
   CustName
FROM <TABLE2> 
WHERE Dept = 'Sales' AND Designation = 'Manager'
```

The SELECT statement often picks multiple records, but all records have max ID column say, 16.

Is there any way to automatically increment the max ID column based on row?

For example:

INSTEAD OF:

16 ........... John

16 ........... Sam

16 ........... Adam

it should pick in this way:

16 ........... John

17 ........... Sam

18 ........... Adam

Comment: Is there a reason you can't turn identity on?  This is why it exists.

Comment: If you turning off happens because you need the inserted ID's have a look to [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: Actually this table is not designed by me. Few guys turned it off, don't know why. Now my stored procedures are crashing and I need to change accordingly.

Comment: Find out why, likely it is an error and shoudl be fixed not worked around. It is very poor practice to increment ids manually, you wil eventailly run into race conditions.

Comment: Yes I understand, but can't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kludge, but it may help you solve the immediate problem.  In the long run, though, it's best to turn IDENTITY back on.

```
DECLARE @Seed INT
SELECT @Seed = MAX(Cust_ID) FROM <table_1>


INSERT INTO <table_1>
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) + @Seed,
   CustName
FROM <TABLE2> 
WHERE Dept = 'Sales' AND Designation = 'Manager'
```

However, this code is likely to break in spectacular ways if you execute multiple instances of it simultaneously.